# YouTube API - The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects

Tags: c#, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get videos from youtube with my C# application, with "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?forMine=true&order=date&type=video&part=snippet&key={key}&access_token={token}" but I receive this error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The API Key and the authentication credential are from different 
projects.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The API Key and the authentication credential are from 
different projects.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developer console API key",
            "url": 
"https://console.developers.google.com/project/{MyProjectCode}/apiui/credential"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CONSUMER_INVALID",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "consumer": "projects/{MyProjectCode}",
          "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

But I can see only 1 API Key and 1 OAuth 2.0 Client ID (with Client ID and Client Secret) on [https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/credentials?authuser=1&project={MyProject}](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/credentials?authuser=1&project=%7BMyProject%7D) site

Could you please help how can I fix this ?

Code:

```
var token = Helper.Decrypt(ytConn.AccessToken);
var url = "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search? 
forMine=true&order=date&type=video&part=snippet&key=" + _key + 
"&access_token=" + token;

videos = Helper.GetFromAPI<Videos>(url, token);
```

it calls this:

```
public static T GetFromAPI<T>(string url, string token)
{            
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    request.Headers.Set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);                

    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    T type = default(T);

    try
    {
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new 
                StreamReader(dataStream))
                {
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    type = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> 
                    (responseFromServer);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and include Your Code.

Comment: Sorry, which one ?

Comment: Which one what? You say your doing this in C#, where's the code?  I need a [example] if you want me to be able to test your issue  I need to see your code not just a url to an endpoint.  I assume you are using the Google .net client library.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: @DaImTo As I see the code not helped a lot.

Comment: actually i couldn't have given you an answer without the code.   So yes the code helped a lot.   I do not sit on stack overflow waiting for users like yourself to add their code you need to either ping me directly in the question or wait for me to spot it.

Comment: @DaImTo There was not any king of offense in my comment,  just thought there is no solution for this. Thank you for the answer, I am testing it

Comment: Really try the client library its much easer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need to change the code, on one day started working again, so most probably the issue was on Youtube side.

Answer (score 0):

You have added an API key, API keys are needed for accessing public data.  They are really only needed to identify your project to Google. You have also included an access token in your request.  Access tokens are used to access private user data.  Access tokens also identify your project so technically speaking you dont need both.

The error message you are getting

> The API Key and the authentication credential are from
> different projects

means that the API key you are using is from one project on Google cloud console and the access token was created using the client credentials from a different project on google cloud console.  While you dont need both there is nothing stopping you from using both other then the fact that they need to be from the same project.

I subject that you just remove the key section from your code. if you are sending an access token there is no need to have key.

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search? 
forMine=true&order=date&type=video&part=snippet + 
"&access_token=" + token;
```

You should consider using the Google api .net client library.

- My [YouTube Data api samples](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Samples/YouTube%20Data%20API)
- Beginner YouTube data api C# video [How to find find the Most Popular videos with YouTube API C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDkKyAMAobA&list=PLws6LF6K-IU_hkQopPXWeZZv8eOEkYqcT&index=2)